# E: Unable to locate package lib-nl

Tags: package-management

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lib-nl

can some one help on this

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add context. Meaning: What you're trying to do/install, what command you used and the full result. Also, it goes without saying, you Ubuntu release/version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library for dealing with netlink sockets is named *libnl-3-200* in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libnl-3-200
```